# Print every second consequtive field in two columns - awk

Tags: awk

Assume the following file

```
#zvview.exe
#begin Present/3
 77191.0000 189.320100          0          0          3          0111110 16    1
-8.072430+6-8.072430+6      77190          0          1         37111110 16    2
         37          2                                            111110 16    3
 8.115068+6 0.000000+0 8.500000+6 6.390560-2 9.000000+6 6.803440-1111110 16    4
 9.500000+6 1.685009+0 1.000000+7 2.582780+0 1.050000+7 3.260540+0111110 16    5
         37          2                                            111110 16   18
```

What I would like to do, is print in two columns, the fields after line 6. This can be done using `NR`. The tricky part is the following : Every second field, should go in one column as well as adding an `E` before the sign, so that the output file will look like this

```
8.115068E+6 0.000000E+0
8.500000E+6 6.390560E-2
9.000000E+6 6.803440E-1
9.500000E+6 1.685009E+0
1.000000E+7 2.582780E+0
1.050000E+7 3.260540E+0
```

From the output file you see that I want to keep in `$6` only `length($6)=10` characters.

How is it possible to do it in awk?

Comment: How do you know where the 6th field ends? Is there always only one digit for the exponent? has the 7th field always the same length? Anything else?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for your comment! I know that I will always have only one digit in the exponent.  About the 7th field it will most probably have always 2 digits.

Comment: How should a script know not to print the contents of the 8th line? Because you only want the 6th and 7th or becasue of something about the contents of the line(s) or what?

Comment: @EdMorton : i will use `NR>= 6 && NR<=whatever` to select the desired lines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to combine @karafka 's answer using `substr`, so the following does the trick!

```
awk 'NR>=6 && NR<=7{$6=substr($6,1,10);for(i=1;i<=6;i+=2) print substr($i,1,8) "E" substr($i,9) FS substr($(i+1),1,8) "E" substr($(i+1),9)}' file
```

and the output is

```
8.115068E+6 0.000000E+0
8.500000E+6 6.390560E-2
9.000000E+6 6.803440E-1
9.500000E+6 1.685009E+0
1.000000E+7 2.582780E+0
1.050000E+7 3.260540E+0
```

Answer (score 2):

can do all in awk but perhaps easier with the unix toolset

```
$ sed -n '6,7p' file | cut -c2-66 | tr ' ' '\n' | pr -2ats' '

8.115068+6 0.000000+0
8.500000+6 6.390560-2
9.000000+6 6.803440-1
9.500000+6 1.685009+0
1.000000+7 2.582780+0
1.050000+7 3.260540+0
```

Here is a `awk` only solution or comparison

```
$ awk 'NR>=6 && NR<=7{$6=substr($6,1,10);
                      for(i=1;i<=6;i+=2) {f[++c]=$i;s[c]=$(i+1)}}
                  END{for(i=1;i<=c;i++) print f[i],s[i]}' file

8.115068+6 0.000000+0
8.500000+6 6.390560-2
9.000000+6 6.803440-1
9.500000+6 1.685009+0
1.000000+7 2.582780+0
1.050000+7 3.260540+0
```

Perhaps shorter version,

```
$ awk 'NR>=6 && NR<=7{$6=substr($6,1,10); 
                      for(i=1;i<=6;i+=2) print $i FS $(i+1)}' file

8.115068+6 0.000000+0
8.500000+6 6.390560-2
9.000000+6 6.803440-1
9.500000+6 1.685009+0
1.000000+7 2.582780+0
1.050000+7 3.260540+0
```

to convert format to standard scientific notation, you can pipe the result to 
`sed` or embed something similar in `awk` script (using gsub).

```
... | sed 's/[+-]/E&/g'

8.115068E+6 0.000000E+0
8.500000E+6 6.390560E-2
9.000000E+6 6.803440E-1
9.500000E+6 1.685009E+0
1.000000E+7 2.582780E+0
1.050000E+7 3.260540E+0
```

Comment: Thank you very for your answer. Can you explain the command, because I am not familiar with `sed`. Thanks!

Comment: `sed` predates `awk`, here it's selecting rows 6 and 7 and printing.  It's similar to `awk 'NR>=6 && NR<=7'` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How can I put an `E` before the sign in each entry?

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for `FIELDWIDTHS`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="9 2 9 2 9 2 9 2 9 2 9 2" }
NR>5 && NR<8 {
    for (i=1;i<NF;i+=4) {
        print $i "E" $(i+1), $(i+2) "E" $(i+3)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
 8.115068E+6  0.000000E+0
 8.500000E+6  6.390560E-2
 9.000000E+6  6.803440E-1
 9.500000E+6  1.685009E+0
 1.000000E+7  2.582780E+0
 1.050000E+7  3.260540E+0
```

If you really want to get rid of the leading blanks then there's various ways to do it (simplest being `gsub(/ /,"",$<field number>)` on the relevant fields) but I left them in because the above allows your output to line up properly if/when your numbers start with a `-`, like they do on line 4 of your sample input.

If you don't have GNU awk, get it as you're missing a LOT of extremely useful functionality.